# Custom Apps wont show up

Tags: sharepoint-addin, 2016, app

I got a SharePoint 2016 where we want to use custom apps, If I add an app to the app catalog it won't show up in the site "apps you can add".
the app management service and subscription settings service are running.
I'm using the site administrator to add the app.

what could be wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Did you ticked the checkbox **"Make this solution available to all sites in the organization"** when you deployed the solution package in the App Catalog Site Collection ?

Your SP2016 farm has been designed in multi-tenancy mode or by default?
The App Catalog Site Collection is on the same Web Application of your target site?